# How to use Dynamic Material Instances with UMG in Unreal Engine 5

Tags: unreal-engine5

I am looking for help with creating a HUD using a Dynamic Material Instance. I followed this guide to make a material for my health bar in my game.

[Link to Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_xI-YsxKS-4)

I created a widget blueprint that has a size box and an image. The image is the MI_HealthBar.

[Image of UI_HealthBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r42oZ.png)

This is the code inside the WBP

[Image of UI_HealthBar Event Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdPhW.png)

Then I made a HUD that uses that UI

[Image of HUD using UI_HealthBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1v1Wu.png)

The problem is that the "FillPercent" does not update. The only way that I have found to update the HUD is to remove the HUD and redraw it when damage is taken. It wont work like a regular progress bar and update when damage is taken. How can I get this to update dynamically? Basically, the FillPercent will not update when the player takes damage. It seems to just draw once and that is it. The only way to update the HUD is to remove from parent and then create widget again and add to viewport.

I have tried saving variables and moving where I draw the HUD. I would then save a reference to the HUD and get the Image and it's Dynamic Material where the player takes damage and tried to Set Scalar on Parameter there but that didn't work. The only successful instance of this working is to remove and re-draw.